# laravel login con multiples tablas y campo extra para validar

Tags: laravel

tengo las siguientes tablas

**usuario**

```
id | nombre | activo
1  | raul   | 1
2  | miguel | 0
```

**empresa**

```
id        | nombre   | activo
10203040  | agrosur  | 1
20304050  | olmos    | 0
```

**usuario_empresa**

```
id | usuario_id |    empresa_id     |  predeterminado  | activo
1  |     1      |     10203040      |        1         |    1
1  |     1      |     20304050      |        0         |    1
2  |     2      |     10203040      |        0         |    1
```

- la idea es modificar el login que ofrece laravel. y validar si el campo **activo** es igual a 1 en todas las tablas
- ademas como puedo asignar datos de la empresa predeterminada dentro de la sesión, para poder usarla como **Auth::user() -> empresa_id** o algo similar para obtener la id de la empresa con la que inicie sesión por defecto.

no tengo mucha experiencia en laravel, apenas pude cambiarle los nombres que por defecto crea la autenticacion de laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con relacion a las variables de sesion, podés cargar los valores en el **AppServiceProvider**, algo así;

```
if (!session()->exists('dat_empresa')) {
  session(['dat_empresa'=>'valor_o_valores']);
}
```

Luego para obtener los valores;

```
Session::get('dat_empresa')
```

Para el manejo de sesiones podés mirar la documentacion oficial que es muy completa https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session

Y con relacion al login, las validaciones las podés hacer en el **LoginController**,  sobreescribiendo el metodo **authenticated**, ahi hacés tus controles si el usuario está con el estado correcto y lo mismo con la empresa.